# Why don't companies register domains at their own registrar?

Tags: domains, domain-registration, domain-registrar

Some well-known registrars like Amazon (Route 53), Google and Namecheap don't register their own domain names (e.g. `amazon.com`, `cloudfront.net`, `google.com` etc.) at their own registrars, while some others do (GoDaddy, NameSilo, Cloudflare etc.).

I wonder why registrars do or don't register their domain names on their own.

Maybe related: [Where do domain name hosts get their own domains?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/92934/85797) (doesn't answer this question directly).

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer will involve speculation, but at the heart of it its a combination of 2 things -

1. History - Namecheap used to be a reseller of ENOM for example.
2. Complexity and cost/benefit -  TLDs have their own registries with their own rules. It can be expensive and difficult - sometimes impossible to become a TLD registrar. If, like Google you have a few domains over a large number of TLDs its likely easier, cheaper and safer overall to work with a company that specialises in domain management (as their registrar claims to do) then do your own. The registrar can leaverage their knowledge across a range of companies all with the same broad reach.

Answer (score 1):

Many companies that are now registrars most probably registered their domains *before* they were themselves registrars (chicken and egg). In the case of Amazon and Google, these domains were registered many many years before they were registrars (which is only a relatively recent side to their business).

`namecheap.com` was registered in 2000, but [Namecheap only became ICANN accredited in 2007](https://www.namecheap.com/blog/the-namecheap-story-at-a-glance/), prior to which they seem to have been a reseller for ENOM (as @davidgo pointed out). And according to `whois.domaintools.com` the domain has never been transferred to a different registrar.

Transferring domains is not without risks (`.com` domains need to be *unlocked* prior to transfer) and these high profile domains are probably more vulnerable than most. Although, according to `whois.domaintools.com` these Amazon and Google domains have been transferred 2 - 3 times in their 20+ year history.

The current registrar for all 3 of these high profile domains is "MarkMonitor Inc", a company that would seem to specialise in brand security of over 20 years, so they are perhaps more suited to the job:

> MarkMonitor Inc. is an American software company founded in 1999. It develops software intended to **protect corporate brands from Internet counterfeiting, fraud, piracy, and cybersquatting**. It also develops and publishes reports on the prevalence of brand abuse on the Internet.
>
> (Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MarkMonitor)

Of course, the registrar could manage/transfer their own domain(s) if they wish (providing they are accredited for the particular TLD<sup>***1**</sup>), but there isn't necessarily any benefit in doing so.

<sup>(***1** Even though [Google support 329 TLDs](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/6010092?hl=en-GB), they don't actually support all the TLDs of domains that they themselves own.)</sup>